# Cucumber JVM using JUnit can't find stepDefinitions

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm having difficult pointing to my stepDefinitions. It exists, it has stuff in it like:

```
@Given("^Mark \"(.*)\" flew a kite$")
    public void mark_flew_a_kite(String kiteName) throws Throwable {
        kiteName = kiteName;
    }

    @When("^The wind blows (\\d+)st (\\d+)$")
    public void the_wind_blows() throws Throwable {

        json = callKiteService(200);

    }
```

**Please note I've changed all the actual method names for stackoverflow and inadvertantly made some of the regex not match. But it matches in the actual code!**

But the test output says that none of the test steps were found and that I need to write them all.

```
Feature: Mark flies kite

Scenario: Mark flew a kite on a windy day [90m# WebServiceTest.feature:3[0m
    [33mGiven [0m[33mMark flew a kite[0m
    [33mWhen [0m[33mMark flies a kite on Dec 1st 2015[0m
    [33mThen [0m[33mThe kite should fly up[0m

1 Scenarios ([33m1 undefined[0m)
3 Steps ([33m3 undefined[0m)
0m0.000s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^Mark flew a kite$")
public void mark_flew_a_kite(String arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^The wind blows (\\d+)st (\\d+)$")
public void the_wind_blows(int arg1, int arg2) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^The kite should fly up$")
public void kite_should_fly(DataTable arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
    // List<YourType>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>> or Map<K,V>.
    // E,K,V must be a scalar (String, Integer, Date, enum etc)
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

[image: IDE view]

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up copying the files into a new cucumber java skeleton and using that instead of the old project. I couldn't find any differences between the two projects other than that the skeleton worked and I have no idea where it was configured that my features had to be located in src/main/resources/Features

I did a search for feature and found nothing.

[Link to skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton)